# node js + login API

Tags: node.js, api, authentication, bcrypt

[image]
I am trying to login with API using bcrypt to hash the password 
problem when  comparing  hash with the original password always  give me output [image] Auth failed1  while username is correct and password is the same .
thanks in advance

[image: s]

```
router.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
const user1 = {
        Username: req.body.Username,
        Password: req.body.Password
    };
    var sql = "SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE Username  = '" + user1.Username + "'";
    db.executeSql(sql, function (data, err) {
        if (err) {
            httpMsgs.show500(req, res, err);
        } else {
            if (isEmptyObject(data)) {
                return res.status(401).json({
                    message: 'Auth Failed'
                });
            } else {
                bcrypt.compare(user1.Password, data.Password, (err, result) => {
                    if (err) {
                        return res.status(401).json({
                            message: "Auth failed1"
                        });
                    }
                    if (result) {
                        return res.status(200).json({
                            message: "Auth successful"
                                        });
                    }
                    res.status(401).json({
                        message: "Auth failed2"
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you check `data.Password` before passing it to compare. Because it is possible that data object is not a single user but an array of users.

Comment: i checked data.password it is contain the hashed Password                that data object is a single user   @ – Nayan

Comment: so the data you pasted was array with [ ],  put `data[0].Password` and it should work.

Comment: it 's work thanks a lot  for your help @– Nayan

Comment: Happy to help, updated the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here response of query, the data variable contains the array of records in unique user case it will have array of length one.

Put `data[0].Password` and it should work.

Better approach is the get the user object as the response rather than the array. Because we should not have `data[0]` in good production code.